# style spinner drop down list

Tags: android, styles, spinner

I have several issues with styling a spinner

1. I need to change the drawable of the spinner(selected view) 
   when the user opens the dropdown list(I tried several selectors
   with different states but nothing works properly)
2. I can`t change the text color on the items in dropdown list (I can change
   color but I need different color for the selected value) you can see in more 
   detail in links below.
3. I can`t remove the dividers from the dropdown.

I don`t want to use custom layout with button and a list to simulate the functionality of spinner(but if there is no solution I will do that).

The style.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/mySpinnerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="mySpinnerStyle" parent="android:Widget.ListView.DropDown">
     <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0px</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme_Dialog_Translucent" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/dialog_title_style</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme_Dialog_Measurment_Data_Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/general_background_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/dialog_title_style</item>
</style>

<style name="dialog_title_style" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

```
 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/res_spinner"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="30dp"
     android:layout_weight="60"
     android:background="@drawable/ref_spinner_selector"
     android:dropDownVerticalOffset="1dp"
     android:dropDownWidth="60dp"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:popupBackground="@null"
     android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

[how the spinner needs to be look like](http://i61.tinypic.com/es2sch.png)

[how the spinner looks like now](http://i61.tinypic.com/25oxf0p.png)

Thanks

Update: 
if anyone will have problems to customize spinners

I manage to fix all the issues using ListPopupWindow

```
private void initPopup()
{
    _lp = new ListPopupWindow(getActivity());
    _lp.setAnchorView(_resTitle);

    ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

    _lp.setBackgroundDrawable(cd);
    _lp.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss()
        {
            _resTitle.setSelected(false);
        }
    });
    _listPopupAdapter = new DataSetListAdapter(getActivity(), _resData);
    _lp.setAdapter(_listPopupAdapter);
}
```

onclick

case R.id.res_title:

```
            if (!_lp.isShowing())
            {
                _resTitle.setSelected(true);
                _lp.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                _lp.show();
                _lp.getListView().setDivider(null);
                _lp.getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
            }
            else
            {
                _resTitle.setSelected(false);
                _lp.dismiss();
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Android does not permit make customization of spinner UI.So
If you want to modify your spinner UI,Then use android popup view where you can put your style UI with effect like drop-down menu
example

```
  spinner=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_Spinner);


    spinner.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            p = new Point();
            p.x = location[0]+(v.getHeight());
            p.y = location[1]+v.getHeight();

            if (p != null)
                showPopup(statusActivity.this, p);

            System.out.println("show popup");
        }
    });




// The method that displays the popup.
private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {
    int popupWidth = 300;
    int popupHeight = 500;

    // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);

    // Creating the PopupWindow
    popup = new PopupWindow(context);
    popup.setContentView(layout);
    popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
    popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
    popup.setFocusable(true);

    // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
    int OFFSET_X = 00;
    int OFFSET_Y = 00;

    // Clear the default translucent background
    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

    // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
    popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);
    ((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setClickable(true);
    ((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView3)).setClickable(true);
    ((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView4)).setClickable(true);
    ((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView5)).setClickable(true);
    ((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView6)).setClickable(true);
    ((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView7)).setClickable(true);
    ((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView8)).setClickable(true);
    ((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView9)).setClickable(true);

}
```

and popup.xml

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/popup"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/popup_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    style="@style/text_orange_heading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select Status"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    style="@style/text_blue_contains"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_white"
    android:tag="Sleeping"
    android:text="Sleeping" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    style="@style/text_blue_contains"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_white"
    android:tag="Available"
    android:text="Available" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    style="@style/text_blue_contains"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_white"
    android:tag="Busy"
    android:text="Busy" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    style="@style/text_blue_contains"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_white"
    android:tag="At work"
    android:text="At work" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    style="@style/text_blue_contains"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_white"
    android:tag="Battery charge low"
    android:text="Battery charge low" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    style="@style/text_blue_contains"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_white"
    android:tag="In meeting"
    android:text="In meeting" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    style="@style/text_blue_contains"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_white"
    android:tag="TMS me later"
    android:text="TMS me later" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    style="@style/text_blue_contains"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_white"
    android:tag="At the toilet"
    android:text="At the toilet" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textCustomize"
    style="@style/text_blue_contains"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:tag="Customize"
    android:text="Customize" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I managed to do this using ListPopupWindow

Comment: example was same of popup menu.